# ASP.net objectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

Is   it    possible to   keep   the same Method name for    both   insert  and  update in   ObjectDatasource?

I   am    using   Save() method for insert   and update.But ObjectDataSource  fires Update  but does not
fire  insert.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  If you set the InsertMethod and UpdateMethod to the same routines, this should work fine.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="CustomerInfoDataSource" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Entities.CustomerInfo"
    InsertMethod="Save" SelectMethod="GetByCustomerId" TypeName="Business.CustomerManager"
    UpdateMethod="Save">
```

Hope this helps!